# Python Awis API giving not defined error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-2.7

I have installed  https://github.com/muhuk/python-awis in order to get the url information from alexa. I have installed it by running `python setup.py install` from terminal.

When I try to run the script, I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pst.py", line 4, in <module>
    api = AwisApi(ACCESS_ID,SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
NameError: name 'AwisApi' is not defined
```

I am using the following code in-order to run the script:

```
 api = AwisApi(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
tree = api.url_info("www.domain.com", "Rank", "LinksInCount")
elem = tree.find("//{%s}StatusCode" % api.NS_PREFIXES["alexa"])
assert elem.text == "Success"
```

Do I have to import something? I am missing something.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you'll need to:
`import awis`

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
api = awis.AwisApi(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import awis
api = awis.AwisApi(ACCESS_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
tree = api.url_info("www.domain.com", "Rank", "LinksInCount")
elem = tree.find("//{%s}StatusCode" % api.NS_PREFIXES["alexa"])
assert elem.text == "Success"
```

Comment: I got this response IOError: All 3 requests failed, latest response code is 403